# How can I open my PWA app from other native app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am implementing a PWA application and a native application on Android. I need to open the native app from PWA app which I know how to do that. Basically I need a URL provided from the native app and open the URL from PWA which will bring the native application. This approach is pretty much like opening google map by clicking its url: `http://maps.apple.com/?address=1,Infinite+Loop,Cupertino,California.`.

Now I have a requirement to open my PWA from the native app. For example, if I share the PWA url through facebook, I'd like other people open the PWA app when they click on the url in facebook if they have installed the PWA. 
How can I achieve that?.

Comment: What if the user installs with something other than Chrome? You may not be able to tell if they installed the PWA with FireFox or Edge browsers.

Comment: If users don't install it, it is fine. What I want to achieve is that if users have installed the PWA, it open it otherwise just load the URL in the default browser.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to tell if if they use mutiple browsers. And a PWA installs differntly in the differnt browsers. And people who use multiple browsers usually do not have a default browser so they can pick when opening a URL.

Comment: When you click on the desktop link added to the home screen it opens in the browser from which it was added.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement anything to do that. Android does it for you. For example, if your PWA is hosted on `https://my-pwa.com` and the user clicks a link with the href `https://my-pwa.com`, Android first looks through your PWAs and if the URL matches, it opens the PWA. Otherwise Android opens the Chrome browser.

Just verified this on an Android 6 device.

Comment: Cool, whether I can pass more parameters on the url?

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't work. I put the url in chrome and it opens the link instead of open my PWA app even I have installed it.

Comment: You put the URL in the Chrome browser address bar, or on in the HTML on Web Page that you opened in Chome?